# Azure AD B2C Login - Disable zoom on web view

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to get the web view that is spawned for login by Azure AD B2C authentication so I can keep it from zooming in Xamarin forms?  It creates havoc with my login form and it's not necessary because I don't have a lot of stuff on the page to begin with.

All of this seems to happens in the background by magic somehow, so it doesn't seem like I can get do anything to the webview itself.

Here's the login page when it loads:
[image]

Here's what happens as soon as you click on the user name textbox:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to make it clearer what you're referring to?

Comment: edited the question to include

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Zoom Button From Azure B2C in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787968/how-to-remove-zoom-button-from-azure-b2c-in-xamarin-forms)