# How to remove Zoom Button From Azure B2C in Xamarin Forms

Tags: html, css, azure, xamarin.forms, active-directory

I have azure b2c running in my xamarin forms app, its work well but the ui customization is so limit. And I have one problem in the login page, signup page and forgot password it has Zoom button in the bottom of corner which is so annoying because sometime when I'm trying to press the signup its press the zoom button instead.

And how I can remove this button because I can't find any setting in the azure b2c i'm using wingtip as my Azure b2c layout from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool) is that because css i use from wingtip template or its because the azure b2c setting or something here is the example. Can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found the answer just add this in your html template

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

instead of make custom renderer in your xamarin forms and it works perfectly